# Not able to remove the back button in sliver app bar

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-sliver

I am using below `SliverAppBar` , I want to remove the back button when I reach this page through `Navigation.pushReplacement`

This SliverAppBar is nested in a page which is in return nested in bottom bar navigation.

How should I remove the back button

```
SliverAppBar(

            expandedHeight: 120.0,
            floating: true,
            pinned: false,
            snap: true,
            elevation: 40,
            backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                centerTitle: true,
                title: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
                  child: Text('Hello'),





                ),


            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `automaticallyImplyLeading = false`

Answer (score 2):

There is a property in SliverAppBar **automaticallyImplyLeading**. Set this to false. By default it is true.

For more information visit [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html)